# Word that encompasses constants and variables, but not literals or classes?

Tags: terminology

Is there a word for a token that has a name, a type, and a value (i.e. can be used in an expression)?

Variables and constants would fit the definition, but literals wouldn't because they don't have names, and classes wouldn't because they don't have values. Properties in C# would fit the definition as well.

Comment: I think this is off-topic and belongs on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I was thinking of asking there, but [like many others](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/are-we-going-down-hill/3140#3140), [I'm wary of the moderation on that site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5161/is-high-profile-user-attrition-a-sign-that-a-subjective-se-wont-work). I don't think it's off-topic though, as there are already 1040 questions under the tag "terminology".

Comment: Fair enough. You convinced me - If I could retract my close vote, I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's close to lvalue in C/C++ though I don't think C# property fits.

Comment: lvalue is pretty close, though from what I understand, it just means "something that can be assigned to, which has an address". I'm not sure constants necessarily fit, since they're often stripped of an actual address upon compilation. I'm willing to accept though if C/C++ couldn't come up with a name, that maybe there isn't actually one.

Comment: Constants are non-modifiable lvalues. Compiler optimization may convert even a modifiable lvalue,such as variable, into non-lvalue - but that's a different question.

Comment: Can you convince me that [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)) is wrong in not mentioning constants? I can't decide whether it's the fact that constants are optimized out that makes it an implementation detail, or the fact that constants are used syntactically similarly that makes it an implementation detail.

Comment: It's not wrong, read inside subsections, there is a full explanation

Comment: Whoops, totally missed that; I just did a ctrl+f for "constant" and assumed it was missing. L-value it is! Thanks!